# Is it possible to use thread_sleep to detect the number of cores

Tags: multithreading

I've an idea to detect the number of cores of a PC but I'm not sure if it works. Here is the code:

```
int sleepSec = 2;  // 2 sec
void funcSleep()
{
    sleep(sleepSec);
}

const int SIZE = 4;
threadArr arr[SIZE];
int begin_time = getCurrentTime();
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    arr[i] = thread_create(funcSleep);
}
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    thread_join(arr[i]);
}
int end_time = getCurrentTime();
print("The number of cores = ");
print(sleepTime * SIZE / (end_time - start_time));
```

If we neglect all of delay, I think the code above could tell me the number of cores of the PC.

In a word, if the strategy of managing multi-threading is: assign a thread to an unused core if possible. The code should works well.
If not, could you explain how a PC processes multithreading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in a reliable way. When one thread is sleeping, other threads can be scheduled (executed) on that same core.

On a single core machine, the first thread would be scheduled. In a few microseconds, the sleep syscall would mean that the kernel scheduler evicted that process (because it's not going to do anything useful in the next 2 seconds, so might as well let some other process run meanwhile). Then, another process would be scheduled, eventually one of yours. That would call the sleep syscall, and a third process gets scheduled. If the computer is otherwise idle, your program would run in roughly 2s on any computer.

There are syscalls you can do which plainly returns the integer number of cpu's in the computer.

N.B. there's no sleep syscall; it's actually that whenever the sleeping threads get scheduled, they look at the time, realize that they haven't slept long enough, and give control back to the kernel scheduler, evicting themselves so that something else can run.

Comment: If it is a single core PC, my code above always needs 8 sec to finish. Am I right? I don't understand why "your program would run in roughly 2s on any computer"

Comment: Is it because my function is `sleep` 2 seconds, instead of doing some real tasks?

Comment: @Thomas `sleep` does not do a busy wait; it let's some other program run on that core while this program is sleeping; otherwise you'd waste a ton of resources. Imagine if your alarm app on your phone took one cpu core all by itself whenever you had an alarm scheduled.

Comment: So the code will spend about 2 seconds because all of tasks are nothing but `sleep`, if each task does a real huge thing (not `sleep`) on a single core machine, I will need 2 * 4 seconds to make all tasks finish. Right?

Comment: How long time does it take to do "a really huge thing"? Depends on so many factors. Technically, you have no way of knowing if it ever finishes.

Comment: I always used `sleep` to simulate some task on a thread, if my code above will spend about 2 seconds to finish, I think I shouldn't do such a simulation anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The way threads are assigned to cores is implementation-specific. By no means is it guaranteed that each thread is assigned a different core, even if there are enough available.

Most JVMs would actually try to do that, but for instance idle - e.g. sleeping - threads could share a core with other threads.

If you want to find out the number of cores, you can do

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

**But**, the Java RT may be set up to use fewer than the number of available cores. [This article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/change-the-processor-affinity-setting-in-windows-7-to-gain-a-performance-edge/) discusses how to change the processor affinity for a JVM under Windows 7.

Moreover, hyperthreading may double the number of apparently available cores.

Therefore, there is no generic, standards-conform way in Java to determine the exact number of cores on a system.